# devtools console cursor is hidden sometimes

Tags: google-chrome, devtools

[image]

---

I tried:

- resizing the window
- move to another tab
- zoom in and out

only restart works

Comment: Any luck finding an answer to this issue?

Comment: @SunnyPro nope. sorry.